# Unable to add library module dependency to dynamic feature module

Tags: android, dependencies, android-instant-apps, dynamic-feature-module

I have a library module and a dynamic feature module. I need the feature module to have a dependency on the library module but I get an error while doing so:

`Unable to resolve dependency for ':my-dynamic-feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :my-library-module.`

I'm trying to add dependency like this: `api project(":my-library-module")`

Any ideas what is causing this error?
TIA

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to define build flavors in the dynamic feature module too. That worked.